# Haskell -> C FFI performance

Tags: c, performance, haskell, marshalling, ffi

This is the dual question of [Performance considerations of Haskell FFI / C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5665209/477476): I would like to call a C function with as small an overhead as possible.

To set the scene, I have the following C function:

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint64_t RESET;
} INPUT;

typedef struct
{
    uint64_t VGA_HSYNC;
    uint64_t VGA_VSYNC;
    uint64_t VGA_DE;
    uint8_t VGA_RED;
    uint8_t VGA_GREEN;
    uint8_t VGA_BLUE;
} OUTPUT;

void Bounce(const INPUT* input, OUTPUT* output);
```

Let's run it from C and time it, with `gcc -O3`:

```c
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.RESET = 0;
    OUTPUT output;

    int cycles = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 60; ++j)
    {
        for (;; ++cycles)
        {
            Bounce(&input, &output);
            if (output.VGA_HSYNC == 0 && output.VGA_VSYNC == 0) break;
        }

        for (;; ++cycles)
        {
            Bounce(&input, &output);
            if (output.VGA_DE) break;
        }
    }

    printf("%d cycles\n", cycles);
}
```

Running it for 25152001 cycles takes ~400 ms:

```
$ time ./Bounce
25152001 cycles

real    0m0.404s
user    0m0.403s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Now let's write some Haskell code to set up FFI (note that `Bool`'s `Storable` instance really does use a full `int`):

```hs
data INPUT = INPUT
    { reset :: Bool
    }

data OUTPUT = OUTPUT
    { vgaHSYNC, vgaVSYNC, vgaDE :: Bool
    , vgaRED, vgaGREEN, vgaBLUE :: Word64
    }
    deriving (Show)

foreign import ccall unsafe "Bounce" topEntity :: Ptr INPUT -> Ptr OUTPUT -> IO ()

instance Storable INPUT where ...
instance Storable OUTPUT where ...
```

And let's do what I believe to be functionally equivalent to our C code from before:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = alloca $ \inp -> alloca $ \outp -> do
    poke inp $ INPUT{ reset = False }

    let loop1 n = do
            topEntity inp outp
            out@OUTPUT{..} <- peek outp
            let n' = n + 1
            if not vgaHSYNC && not vgaVSYNC then loop2 n' else loop1 n'
        loop2 n = do
            topEntity inp outp
            out <- peek outp
            let n' = n + 1
            if vgaDE out then return n' else loop2 n'
        loop3 k n
          | k < 60 = do
              n <- loop1 n
              loop3 (k + 1) n
          | otherwise = return n

    n <- loop3 (0 :: Int) (0 :: Int)
    printf "%d cycles" n
```

I build it with GHC 8.6.5, using `-O3`, and I get.. more than 3 seconds!

```
$ time ./.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/sim-ffi/sim-ffi
25152001 cycles

real   0m3.468s
user   0m3.146s
sys    0m0.280s
```

And it's not a constant overhead at startup, either: if I run for 10 times the cycles, I get roughly 3.5 seconds from C and 34 seconds from Haskell.

**What can I do to reduce the Haskell -> C FFI overhead?**

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but it requires too much effort. Can you somehow provide a complete example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "What can I do to reduce the Haskell -> C FFI overhead?"

I mean, the main thing would be doing less of it. You keep marshalling/unmarshalling things in a tight loop, so of course that’s going to be slow.

Comment: Do you ever need the Haskell structure in haskell?  If you can just keep it as a pointer to memory and have a few test functions such as `vgaVSYNC :: Ptr INPUT -> IO Bool` then that will save a log of copying, allocation, GC work on every call.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: please see my answer on why that is not a problem once `peek` is inlined.

Comment: @Cubic: but the whole point of the eventual real program I am writing (not this stripped-down one) is to process the fields of `OUTPUT` for every single iteration of `topEntity`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to reduce the overhead so that the 25 M calls now finish in 1.2 seconds. The changes were:

1. Make `loop1`, `loop2` and `loop3` strict in the `n` argument (using `BangPatterns`)
2. Add an `INLINE` pragma to `peek` in `OUTPUT`'s `Storable` instance

Point #1 is silly, of course, but that's what I get for not profiling earlier. That change alone gets me to 1.5 seconds....

Point #2, however, makes a ton of sense and is generally applicable. It also addresses the comment from @Thomas M. DuBuisson:

> Do you ever need the Haskell structure in haskell? If you can just keep it as a pointer to memory and have a few test functions such as `vgaVSYNC :: Ptr OUTPUT -> IO Bool` then that will save a log of copying, allocation, GC work on every call.

In the eventual full program, I do need to look at all the fields of `OUTPUT`. However, with `peek` inlined, GHC is happy to do the case-of-case transformation, so I can see in Core that now there is no `OUTPUT` value allocated; the output of `peek` is consumed directly.